# What's another word for traffic in a rural preindustrial or medieval environment?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's another word for traffic in a rural preindustrial or medieval type environment?

Traffic just feels so modern to me, cars and trucks, and doesn't seem to fit in a time and place where there are no automobiles.

What would a better word to describe the traffic of horses and wagons, or something along those lines?

Comment: If you mean traffic in the sense of vehicles competing for space on the roads, there wasn't much in the way of roads in rural preindustrial or medieval environments. There were some well-worn paths but generally, if there was another vehicle "in the way", you just aimed in a slightly different direction, not that there were that many vehicles going from the same place, to the same place, or vice versa, at the same time. If you mean traffic in the generic sense of the overall movement of vehicles, I'm not sure there was enough that someone would have recognized the need for a word.

Comment: Guess I'm thinking more in the generic sense, as oppose to competition. A single horse or wagon could be referred to as traffic, but feels like overkill.

Comment: Maybe the road was full... https://www.google.com/search?q=%22road%20was%20full%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1838&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Clare, I also though of preindustrial cities, but the question is specific about rural.

Comment: Do you want a word we could use today to talk about movement of people and vehicles in thoses days (say in a History essay) or a word that people would use in those days (say for a period novel)? Same question for you "road" question.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence with a blank for the words usage? Could **congestion** work?

Comment: The question wording is a little ambiguous.  "Traffic" can be used in a generic sense to refer to the general movement of vehicles (in the sense that transcontinental traffic would refer to the movement of vehicles across the continent, or traffic between A and B would refer to the flow in general between those points).  It can also refer to the degree of congestion on a road at a given time.  Which meaning are you going for?  Also, it isn't clear what "or medieval environment" refers to.  Is this also limited to a rural setting, just an earlier time period, or does it include medieval cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oldest meaning of *traffic* (trade, commerce, business) has been with us since the 15th century, but it has only signified "people and vehicles coming and going" since the 1820s. Thus the OP would be quite correct to assume a person from the medieval ages would not have used the word "traffic" to suggest a flow of vehicles and people. With the guidance of *etymonline*, may I suggest the following alternatives:

- **The streets were *busy***

> ***[busy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=busy)***
>   Old English *bisig* "careful, anxious," later "continually employed or occupied,"

- **The lanes *bustled***
- **The *bustle* of the city**

> ***[bustle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bustling)***
>   "be active," 1570s (bustling "noisy or excited activity" is from early 15c.),

- **The way was *crowded***

> ***[crowded](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=crowded)***
>   Old English *crudan* "to press, crush."

Dictionary.com dates *[crowded](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crowded?s=t)* between 1605-1615

***[Way](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=way)*** is an archaic term for *road*, derived from Old English *weg* (ca. 500-1100).  In fact, **portweg** meant "the way to town" or "public road"

Comment: Really like 'bustle', gives the impression of activity without the modern feel I get from 'traffic'.

Comment: @GRW thank you for accepting the answer, and I'm delighted you like the suggestion *bustle*.